# How to print something in WPF without using controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I'm newbie in WPF and I'm trying to print student's exam papers using WPF and I'm creating exam papers using `System.Drawing.Graphics` and now I want to print them.

But it seems every printable thing in WPF is somehow a control. I have two problems:

1. I don't know how can I print something that I've created via `Graphics` Like WinForms `PrintDocument` (that has it's own problems)
2. I don't know how to create my exampaper in WPF like what I did with graphics.

would you help me with any of theses questions?

Comment: There's a nice [sample application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Printing-Overview-f28c541a) which seems to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the utilize the [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which is not WPF specific.  This class allows you to send output to a printer.  The PrintPage event should be handled, where you utilize the PrintPageEventArgs to obtain a Graphics context; which is used to draw the exam to the printer output.  This is considered the Winforms way of printing.

WPF has enhanced [printing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742418(v=vs.110).aspx) support, provided by the [System.Printing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.  These printing services are used to manage print jobs, and to discover print queues, and configured printers.  Printing in WPF is usually performed by generating an XPS document, by utilizing the [XpsDocumentWriter](http://XpsDocumentWriter) class & methods. However, GDI printing is available as well, which is what you'd likely need, because of the use of System.Drawing.Graphics.  Refer to the GDI Print Path section, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742418(v=vs.110).aspx).